# How to fresh navigate to specific screen?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm new in React Native

I have route looks :

> ScreenA -> ScreenB -> ScreenC

Now i want to fresh navigate to ScreenA from ScreenC, I use `this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenA');`

> **But i get the fact**, i get previous screenA (not new one) or i can say
>   it is like back to previous screen method. What i want similar to
>   Intent intent = new Intent(ScreenA) in Android Native. Can anyone help
>   to solve it?

Updated :

I have 2 routes group, it may lead to the real problem :

```
StackNavigator {
 screenA,
 screenB
}

TabNavigator {
 screenC
}
```

> I can't move screenC to screenA using .push or .dispatch. But working
>   well using .navigate. But if i use .navigate , screenA is previous
>   screen not new screen (same like before i move to screenB). I want move from screenC to a new screenA not previous screenA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';
//Reset and navigate
    const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [
              NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'YourScreen' })
            ]
          })
          this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
//Or Navigate
this.props.navigation.navigate("YourScreen");
//Similar to navigate, push will move you forward to a new route in the stack
this.props.navigation.push(routeName, params, action)
```

For more refer [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/api-reference.html)

Comment: Unfortunately not working. Not error but nothing happen when change navigate to push.

Comment: Cannot find StackActions.

Comment: can u explain how u r doing

Comment: I try use push like : this.props.navigation.push(routeName, params, action)

But nothing happen. if i change to navigate it is move to next page.

Comment: @Crocodile have u tried like this this.props.navigation.push(routeName);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182080/discussion-between-prasanth-s-and-crocodile).

Comment: I already find the solution why .push doesn't work. I already post my solution. I will accept this answer as correct answer because my main question is to call new screenA. And .push method is correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

If you use `react-navigation`, you can use `push` instead of `navigate` for making a new screen.

```
this.props.navigation.push('ScreenA');
```

But other screens remain in stack in this case.

[Official Doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#push)

### Why

In `StackNavigation`, `navigate` is worked according to  screen's stack. But `push` works push the specific screen to stack without checking duplication.

If you want to custom current stack, using [reset](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset) can be another option.

Comment: I don't know why it not working. I have 2 routes group :

1. StackNavigator (ScreenA)
2. TabNavigator (ScreenC)

If i push ScreenC to ScreenA it's nothing happen

Answer (score 3):

Try this :
First of all import StackNavigator & your all screen in App.js file Like this

```
import { StackNavigator, SwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

   import ScreenA  from './ScreenA';
   import ScreenB  from './ScreenB';`enter code here`
   import ScreenC  from './ScreenC';

export default class App extends Component { 
render() {
   return (
       <Nav />
   );
 }
const Nav = StackNavigator({
   ScreenA  : { screen: ScreenA },
   ScreenB  : { screen: ScreenB },
   ScreenC  : { screen: ScreenC },
 });
```

When ScreenA will be open then call

```
  this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB');  // to navigate
```

You can try also

```
  this.props.navigation.push('ScreenB');  to navigate
```

if you want to go to the previous screen A you just need to call

```
 this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

Comment: I don't know why it not working. I have 2 routes group : 1. StackNavigator (ScreenA) 2. TabNavigator (ScreenC) If i push ScreenC to ScreenA it's nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer (but i'm not sure it's a best practice or not) :

related to all answer i get a same solution is use .push . And i try to change navigate with push method but first time i try it's failed. And after a hour try i get the fact that this way works for me :

```
 this.props.navigation.push('TabNavigator') //Call the navigator name not screenname when cross two different navigator.
```

> You can share your idea if you know better solution. thank you